# What is the value of xs[100] after this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not sure if this belongs here but it was a question from my CS exam.

> What is the value of `xs[100]` after this code?
>
> ```
> xs = [-1, 0, 1]
> for k in range(98):
>  xs.append(xs[k])
> ```
>
> 1. It causes a compile-time error.
> 2. It causes a run-time error.
> 3. `–1`
> 4. `0`
> 5. `1`

So far I figured that `xs.append(xs[k])` keeps appending `-1`, `0`, `1` in that order to the list `xs`. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: You could just try and see what happens.

Comment: have you tried running it?

Comment: Actually, compile time error was the correct answer because the code you posted had an `e2` codepoint where the `-` should have been :-) But I assume that was a transcription problem so I've fixed it.

Comment: Perhaps it was not obvious but in cs exams you are not allowed a computer hence no IDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this loop you will have a list contain `98+3=101` element that the 100's element would be `0` because `101%3= 2`.then you must choose the second element from `-1,0,1`

*Note* that the `append` method of list will change the list in-place, so after each iteration you will iterate on the new list,thus it doesn't raise an `IndexError`

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you need ask, you can just run it in Python and *see:*

```
pax$ cat qq.py
xs = [-1, 0, 1]
for k in range(98):
    xs.append(xs[k])
print xs[100]

pax$ python qq.py
0
```

If you *can't* run it for some reason, you just have to realise that you're appending those elements in order 98 times. That's `-1, 0, 1` 32 times (for a total of 96), then `-1` and `0` as the final two.

And, since you have `3 + 98 = 101` elements, index 100 (the 101st) is the final element, which is `0`.